# Maven disable copying artifact to local repository

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to disable one artifact from the project to be installed to local repository on install phase. 
According to the maven webpages(http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html#skip), there should be a parameter skip, but it's not in the xsd of model version 4.0.0 and is not working.

Here's what I think should work, but does not:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

How can I do that? I need to keep the install phase intact. I need a change only for a single artifact. I also need to have it in the pom, not as a command line parameter.

```
Maven version: 3.0.4
Maven-install-plugin version: 2.3
```

Comment: show us your complete pom

Comment: or the relevant versions

Comment: It's a big project with tens of pom. This is a dependent module, but there are no settings overriding maven-install-plugin configuration anywhere else. I'll add the versions of the sw

Comment: Ah... I see. The skip is since version 2.4 of the plugin

Comment: The installation of an artifact to the local repository is a prerequisite. So it does not make sense to prevent installation of artifacts in the local repository. The question is why do you need such thing? Or do you have a multi module build where you like to create only a single module new? If yes you should take a look at `mvn -pl --amd module install`?

Comment: The problem is that intellij idea have some problems with debugging when I have this particular artifact deployed in my local repository.
That's why I want to install everything except for this single artifact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was using old version of the maven-install-plugin.

Parameter "skip" is there since version 2.4.